# React.createElement: type is invalid --expected a string or function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, visual-web-developer

Used react (17.0.1) , react - dom (6.2.1) , react - router - dom (6.2.1) on my Visual Studio Code but getting the following error in the browser console:

***Error:***

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of 'App'.

**index js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import { initContract } from './utils'

window.nearInitPromise = initContract()
  .then(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.querySelector('#root')
    )
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

***App js***

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import React from 'react'
import { login, logout } from './utils'
import './global.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Container, Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown} from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Components/Home'
import NewPoll from './Components/NewPoll'
import PollingStation from './Components/PollingStation'

import getConfig from './config'
const { networkId } = getConfig(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')

export default function App() {

return (
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/'>
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path='/PollingStation'>
      <PollingStation />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path='/NewPoll'>
     <NewPoll />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` version 6 the `Switch` component was replaced by the `Routes` component, and the routed components should be rendered on the `Route` component's `element` prop.

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/PollingStation' element={<PollingStation />} />
    <Route path='/NewPoll' element={<NewPoll />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```